# How can we execute an unhandled-exception type exit "early"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, exit

How can we exit a script with an unhandled exception trace-back, going through every catch-statement in the outer try-catch blocks we are nested inside of?

Supposed we define the following functions:

```
import sys

def foo():
    try:
        bar()
        list()[592]
    except IndexError:
        print('`foo()` be handling error generated by list()[592]')
    return

def bar():
    try:
        list()[345]
    except IndexError:
        pass
        ### MAGIC GOES HERE ###
    return
```

Now, we make the call:
    foo()

What I would like, is for the catch-statement in `bar()` to kill the process.

We do not want `foo()` to catch the `IndexError`, and definitely do *not* want to print `'foo()' be handling error generated by list()[592]`.

If we replace `### MAGIC GOES HERE ###` with something like `sys.exit(-20374290374)`, then we successfully kill the process, but there is no trace-back, and there is no information regarding an "uncaught" exception.

How can we exit as if the exception was uhandled, without first going through all of the outer try-catching blocks?

Answer (score 1):

You raise something that is not catched:

```
import sys

class MyException(Exception):
    pass

def foo():
    try:
        bar()
        list()[592]
    except IndexError:
        print('`foo()` be handling error generated by list()[592]')
    return

def bar():
    try:
        list()[345]
    except IndexError: 
        raise MyException("step out")
    return



foo()
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 26, in <module>
    foo()
  File "main.py", line 10, in foo
    bar()
  File "main.py", line 21, in bar
    raise MyException("step out")
__main__.MyException: step out
```

In case you somewhere catch the base `Exception` (-you should not-) you need to check for your special kind and reraise it:

```
except Exception as e:
    if isinstance(e,MyException):
        raise # e not needed, raise rethrows last one
    print('`foo()` be handling error generated by list()[592]')
```